# Create report using multiple queries

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a report, combining multiple queries into a single report without limiting the report to a single query.

Specifically I have 10 different queries and I'm wanting to count the returned tables and place the number on a report. If qry_members returns 108 cells from a table then I want to count the cells without pulling specific information from the query. If tried a few different things I've read on the net, but they all seem to return errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, an Access report cannot be tied to multiple data sources.

However, what you are trying to accomplish can easily be done with a form (or report, whatever you prefer) and the [DCount](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DCount-Function-f6b5d78b-ad0b-4e42-be7a-11a64acbf3d3) function. First, create a textbox in the form/report and in the "Control Source" of the textbox, paste in the following:

```
=DCount("*", "qry_members")
```

This will return how many records are currently in the query. Copy that textbox 9 more times (one for each query) and just update the second parameter of the DCount function where the query name is.